# Enyo Trying to detect when web service does not work

Tags: enyo

It seems like when my web service has a error, the onFailure method is not being called.  A example is if the file is not on the server, nether   or  gets called.  So my all has a button for the user to press.  If the web service does not exist, nothing happens.

I’m assuming there is a way for my program to detec these erros so I can display a message?????

Code snippet
    {name: "getHistory", kind: "WebService", 
    onSuccess: "gotHistory",
    onFailure: "gotHistoryFailure",
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8500/icechat/server/loadhistory.cfm"
        },

```
 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Call back, called when the history data has been loaded from web services
 gotHistory: function(inSender, inResponse) {

    // Convert data from server to a jason object
    // NOTE: The string should be checked first for embeded javascrip code

         this.serverReply2= inResponse;
     this.$.list.render();
 },

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Called if the history data could not be loaded from the web service
 gotHistoryFailed: function()
 {
    alert("got infortion failed"); // this never goes off
 },
```

Comment: If you're running in webOS as an application, know that alert() is a no-op -- you need some other mechanism, like using `enyo.log` to note the failure.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ancient question, but just in case someone else has a similar problem:
One issue here is that the function is named `gotHistoryFailed`, and the kind definition has `onFailure: gotHistoryFailure` The names have to match exactly, or the handler will not be called.